# fastlane gym `Could not find rake-13.0.3 in any of the sources`

Tags: ios, ruby, xcode, fastlane, fastlane-gym

When I run the gym command I get this weird error.

```
[16:20:23]: ▸ Could not find rake-13.0.3 in any of the sources
[16:20:23]: ▸ Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

Here is the full log:

```
[16:20:09]: Setting Provisioning Profile type to 'ad-hoc'
[16:20:09]: -----------------
[16:20:09]: --- Step: gym ---
[16:20:09]: -----------------
[16:20:10]: Resolving Swift Package Manager dependencies...
[16:20:10]: $ xcodebuild -resolvePackageDependencies -workspace Runner.xcworkspace -scheme prod
[16:20:11]: ▸ Command line invocation:
[16:20:11]: ▸     /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -resolvePackageDependencies -workspace Runner.xcworkspace -scheme prod
[16:20:14]: ▸ resolved source packages:
[16:20:14]: $ xcodebuild -showBuildSettings -workspace Runner.xcworkspace -scheme prod
[16:20:17]: Command timed out after 3 seconds on try 1 of 4, trying again with a 6 second timeout...
[16:20:22]: Detected provisioning profile mapping: {:"com.example.app"=>"match AdHoc com.example.app", :"com.example.app.dev"=>"match AdHoc com.example.app.dev", :"com.example.app.red"=>"match AdHoc com.example.app.red"}

+-----------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                   Summary for gym 2.172.0                                                    |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------+
| workspace                                                       | Runner.xcworkspace                                         |
| scheme                                                          | prod                                                       |
| output_directory                                                | ../build/ios/iphoneos                                      |
| output_name                                                     | Runner_adhoc_prod                                          |
| export_method                                                   | ad-hoc                                                     |
| export_options.provisioningProfiles.com.example.app             | match AdHoc com.example.app                                |
| export_options.provisioningProfiles.com.example.app.dev         | match AdHoc com.example.app.dev                            |
| export_options.provisioningProfiles.com.example.app.red         | match AdHoc com.example.app.red                            |
| destination                                                     | generic/platform=iOS                                       |
| build_path                                                      | /Users/long1eu/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2021-01-28 |
| clean                                                           | false                                                      |
| silent                                                          | false                                                      |
| skip_package_ipa                                                | false                                                      |
| skip_package_pkg                                                | false                                                      |
| result_bundle                                                   | false                                                      |
| buildlog_path                                                   | ~/Library/Logs/gym                                         |
| skip_profile_detection                                          | false                                                      |
| skip_package_dependencies_resolution                            | false                                                      |
| disable_package_automatic_updates                               | false                                                      |
| use_system_scm                                                  | false                                                      |
| xcode_path                                                      | /Applications/Xcode.app                                    |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------+

[16:20:22]: $ set -o pipefail && xcodebuild -workspace Runner.xcworkspace -scheme prod -destination 'generic/platform=iOS' -archivePath /Users/long1eu/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2021-01-28/Runner_adhoc_prod\ 2021-01-28\ 16.20.22.xcarchive archive | tee /Users/long1eu/Library/Logs/gym/Runner_prod-prod.log | xcpretty
[16:20:23]: ▸ Could not find rake-13.0.3 in any of the sources
[16:20:23]: ▸ Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
[16:38:06]: Exit status: 7

+---------------+-------------------------+
|            Build environment            |
+---------------+-------------------------+
| xcode_path    | /Applications/Xcode.app |
| gym_version   | 2.172.0                 |
| export_method | ad-hoc                  |
| sdk           | iPhoneOS14.4.sdk        |
+---------------+-------------------------+

[16:38:06]: ▸ Command line invocation:
[16:38:06]: ▸     
[16:38:06]: 
[16:38:06]: ⬆️  Check out the few lines of raw `xcodebuild` output above for potential hints on how to solve this error
[16:38:06]:   For the complete and more detailed error log, check the full log at:
[16:38:06]:   /Users/long1eu/Library/Logs/gym/Runner_prod-prod.log
[16:38:06]: 
[16:38:06]: Looks like fastlane ran into a build/archive error with your project
[16:38:06]: It's hard to tell what's causing the error, so we wrote some guides on how
[16:38:06]: to troubleshoot build and signing issues: https://docs.fastlane.tools/codesigning/getting-started/
[16:38:06]: Before submitting an issue on GitHub, please follow the guide above and make
[16:38:06]: sure your project is set up correctly.
[16:38:06]: fastlane uses `xcodebuild` commands to generate your binary, you can see the
[16:38:06]: the full commands printed out in yellow in the above log.
[16:38:06]: Make sure to inspect the output above, as usually you'll find more error information there
```

fastlane env

fastlane environment

#### Stack

| Key | Value |
| --- | --- |
| OS | 10.15.6 |
| Ruby | 2.7.2 |
| Bundler? | true |
| Git | git version 2.24.3 (Apple Git-128) |
| Installation Source | ~/.gem/ruby/2.7.0/bin/fastlane |
| Host | Mac OS X 10.15.6 (19G2005) |
| Ruby Lib Dir | /usr/local/Cellar/ruby@2.7/2.7.2/lib |
| OpenSSL Version | OpenSSL 1.1.1i 8 Dec 2020 |
| Is contained | false |
| Is homebrew | false |
| Is installed via Fabric.app | false |
| Xcode Path | /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/ |
| Xcode Version | 12.4 |

#### System Locale

| Error |
| --- |
| No Locale with UTF8 found |

#### fastlane files:

`./fastlane/Fastfile`

```rb
# frozen_string_literal: true

update_fastlane
default_platform(:ios)

BUILD_OUTPUT_ = '../build/ios/iphoneos'
APPSTORE_CONNECT_API_KEY_PATH_ = '../private/key.json'

def setup_ci(type, env)
  keychain_name = 'CI'
  keychain_password = ENV['MATCH_PASSWORD']

  create_keychain(
      name: keychain_name,
      password: keychain_password,
      default_keychain: true,
      unlock: true,
      timeout: 3600,
      lock_when_sleeps: false
  )
  match(
      type: type,
      force_for_new_devices: true,
      keychain_name: keychain_name,
      keychain_password: keychain_password,
      api_key_path: APPSTORE_CONNECT_API_KEY_PATH_
  )
  sh('security list-keychains -d user')
  sh('security default-keychain -d user')
  sh("security find-identity -v -p codesigning #{keychain_name}")

  app_identifier = "com.example.app#{env == "prod" ? "" : ".#{env}"}"

  team_id = ENV["sigh_#{app_identifier}_#{type}_team-id"]
  identity = "Apple Distribution: ORG (#{team_id})"
  profile = ENV["sigh_#{app_identifier}_#{type}"]
  profile_name = ENV["sigh_#{app_identifier}_#{type}_profile-name"]

  update_code_signing_settings(
      use_automatic_signing: false,
      path: 'Runner.xcodeproj',
      team_id: team_id,
      profile_uuid: profile,
      profile_name: profile_name,
      code_sign_identity: identity
  )
end

def build(type, export_method, env)
  cocoapods
  if is_ci
    setup_ci(type, env)
  else
    match(type: type, force_for_new_devices: true, api_key_path: APPSTORE_CONNECT_API_KEY_PATH_)
  end

  gym(
      workspace: 'Runner.xcworkspace',
      scheme: env,
      output_directory: BUILD_OUTPUT_,
      output_name: "Runner_#{type}_#{env}.ipa",
      export_method: export_method
  )
end

platform :ios do
  desc 'Build ipa for Firebase App Distribution'
  lane :build_firebase do |values|
    build('adhoc', 'ad-hoc', values[:env])
  end

  desc 'Build ipa for App Store and upload'
  lane :build_appstore do |values|
    build('appstore', 'app-store', values[:env])
    upload_to_app_store(
      run_precheck_before_submit: false,
      api_key_path: APPSTORE_CONNECT_API_KEY_PATH_
    )
  end

  desc 'Add new device'
  lane :register do |values|
    register_devices(
      devices: {
        values[:name] => values[:udid],
      },
      api_key_path: APPSTORE_CONNECT_API_KEY_PATH_
    )
  end
end
```

`./fastlane/Appfile`

```rb
apple_id("username@gmail.com")
team_id("TEAM_ID")
```

#### fastlane gems

| Gem | Version | Update-Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| fastlane | 2.172.0 | ✅ Up-To-Date |

#### Loaded fastlane plugins:

**No plugins Loaded**

**Loaded gems**

| Gem | Version |
| --- | --- |
| did_you_mean | 1.4.0 |
| bundler | 2.2.7 |
| uri | 0.10.0 |
| rake | 13.0.3 |
| CFPropertyList | 3.0.3 |
| concurrent-ruby | 1.1.8 |
| i18n | 1.8.7 |
| minitest | 5.14.3 |
| thread_safe | 0.3.6 |
| tzinfo | 1.2.9 |
| activesupport | 5.2.4.4 |
| public_suffix | 4.0.6 |
| addressable | 2.7.0 |
| httpclient | 2.8.3 |
| json | 2.5.1 |
| algoliasearch | 1.27.5 |
| artifactory | 3.0.15 |
| atomos | 0.1.3 |
| aws-eventstream | 1.1.0 |
| aws-partitions | 1.420.0 |
| aws-sigv4 | 1.2.2 |
| jmespath | 1.4.0 |
| aws-sdk-core | 3.111.2 |
| aws-sdk-kms | 1.41.0 |
| aws-sdk-s3 | 1.87.0 |
| babosa | 1.0.4 |
| claide | 1.0.3 |
| fuzzy_match | 2.0.4 |
| nap | 1.1.0 |
| netrc | 0.11.0 |
| ffi | 1.14.2 |
| ethon | 0.12.0 |
| typhoeus | 1.4.0 |
| cocoapods-core | 1.10.0.rc.1 |
| cocoapods-deintegrate | 1.0.4 |
| cocoapods-downloader | 1.4.0 |
| cocoapods-plugins | 1.0.0 |
| cocoapods-search | 1.0.0 |
| cocoapods-trunk | 1.5.0 |
| cocoapods-try | 1.2.0 |
| colored2 | 3.1.2 |
| escape | 0.0.4 |
| fourflusher | 2.3.1 |
| gh_inspector | 1.1.3 |
| molinillo | 0.6.6 |
| ruby-macho | 1.4.0 |
| nanaimo | 0.3.0 |
| xcodeproj | 1.19.0 |
| cocoapods | 1.10.0.rc.1 |
| colored | 1.2 |
| highline | 1.7.10 |
| commander-fastlane | 4.4.6 |
| declarative | 0.0.20 |
| declarative-option | 0.1.0 |
| digest-crc | 0.6.3 |
| unf_ext | 0.0.7.7 |
| unf | 0.1.4 |
| domain_name | 0.5.20190701 |
| dotenv | 2.7.6 |
| emoji_regex | 3.2.1 |
| excon | 0.78.1 |
| faraday-net_http | 1.0.1 |
| multipart-post | 2.0.0 |
| ruby2_keywords | 0.0.4 |
| faraday | 1.3.0 |
| http-cookie | 1.0.3 |
| faraday-cookie_jar | 0.0.7 |
| faraday_middleware | 1.0.0 |
| fastimage | 2.2.1 |
| jwt | 2.2.2 |
| memoist | 0.16.2 |
| multi_json | 1.15.0 |
| os | 1.1.1 |
| signet | 0.14.1 |
| googleauth | 0.15.0 |
| mini_mime | 1.0.2 |
| uber | 0.1.0 |
| representable | 3.0.4 |
| retriable | 3.1.2 |
| google-api-client | 0.38.0 |
| rexml | 3.2.4 |
| webrick | 1.7.0 |
| google-apis-core | 0.2.1 |
| google-apis-iamcredentials_v1 | 0.1.0 |
| google-apis-storage_v1 | 0.1.0 |
| google-cloud-env | 1.4.0 |
| google-cloud-errors | 1.0.1 |
| google-cloud-core | 1.5.0 |
| google-cloud-storage | 1.30.0 |
| mini_magick | 4.11.0 |
| plist | 3.6.0 |
| rubyzip | 2.3.0 |
| security | 0.1.3 |
| naturally | 2.2.1 |
| simctl | 1.6.8 |
| slack-notifier | 2.3.2 |
| terminal-notifier | 2.0.0 |
| unicode-display_width | 1.7.0 |
| terminal-table | 1.8.0 |
| tty-screen | 0.8.1 |
| tty-cursor | 0.7.1 |
| tty-spinner | 0.9.3 |
| word_wrap | 1.0.0 |
| rouge | 2.0.7 |
| xcpretty | 0.3.0 |
| xcpretty-travis-formatter | 1.0.1 |

*generated on:* **2021-01-28**

Comment: That's a lot of info, but not a lot of context! What exactly is your question? Is all the info from some issue template or something?

Comment: I think it's the other way arround if you ask me. I have a lot of context so I don't get answer, `o you need to do that stupid thing` that I did already since I spend 8 hours on the issue already.

Comment: I managed to solve this by completely removing ruby, ~/.rvn and ~/.gem.

Comment: Glad you solved it :-)

Comment: So the problem in this case is that when you install ruby using brew flutter is still using the version that you have installed on you mac. So what I ended up doing and works perfectly is to install everything using rvm